# Obter informações do Twitter sem o uso da API com cURL

Tags: php, libcurl, twitter-api

Possuo o seguinte código:

```
$url = 'https://twitter.com/' . $username;

$user = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($user, [
      CURLOPT_URL             => $url,
      CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST   => 'GET',
      CURLOPT_CAINFO          => 'cacert-2017-06-07.pem',
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true,
      CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER  => false,
      CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST  => 2,
      CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER      => [
        "Content-type:text/html;charset=utf-8",
      ],
      CURLOPT_USERAGENT       => $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],
      CURLOPT_HEADER          => true,
      CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION  => true,
      CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS       => 2,
      CURLOPT_REDIR_PROTOCOLS => CURLPROTO_HTTP | CURLPROTO_HTTPS,
      CURLOPT_POSTREDIR       => 2,
      CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER     => 1,
      CURLOPT_ENCODING        => "gzip"
  ]
);
$user_info = json_encode(curl_exec($user));
//$user_info = json_decode(curl_exec($user));

var_dump($user_info);
echo $user_info;
```

Bom, isto me retorna:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de extrair informações como:

**Screen_name, Name, Profile_img, etc**

Um amigo dono de um site disse que é possível, mas ele não quis dar o braço a torcer e me ensinar, qual a lógica por trás? É possível?

Monitorando o `network` obtive isto:

```
-H "accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br"
-H "accept-language: pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4"
-H "upgrade-insecure-requests: 1"
-H "user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36"
-H "accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8"
-H "cache-control: max-age=0"
-H "authority: twitter.com"
```

Comment: Eu já fiz de tudo estou desde ontem tantando debugar isso, e não entendi esta parte **"Algum motivo em especial para não utilizar cURL?"**

Comment: Li o título errado. Erro meu. Tinha lido "Obter informações sem cURL". Perdão.

Comment: De uma olhada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/218866/3635

Comment: Opa, aqui já está resolvido, mas vou ler.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, vou abrir uma pergunta, sobre cURL e token será que pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A página do Twitter aparentemente possui um campo `input[type=hidden]` com o JSON dos dados, o que facilita muito a nossa vida. O resultado obtido em:

```
$user_info = curl_exec($user);
```

Nada mais é que a resposta HTTP obtida quando feita a requisição. Para pegar apenas o corpo da resposta, isto é, o código HTML, basta fazer:

```
$header_size = curl_getinfo($user, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
$header = substr($user_info, 0, $header_size);
$body = substr($user_info, $header_size);
```

Assim, `$header` será os cabeçalhos da resposta HTTP e `$body` o código HTML. Para analisar este código, utilizamos a classe nativa `DOMDocument` (nunca utilize regex):

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($body);
```

O `@` na segunda linha é para ocultar mensagens de avisos geradas devido à erros no HTML da página do Twitter (vários elementos com mesmo `id`). O campo supracitado que possui o JSON é:

```
<input type="hidden" id="init-data" class="json-data" value="..." />
```

Então basta buscarmos pelo id `init-data` no DOM:

```
$json = $dom->getElementById("init-data")->getAttribute("value");
```

Assim, utilizamos `json_decode` para converter para um objeto:

```
$data = json_decode($json);
```

E podemos acessar as informações desejadas:

```
echo "Nome: ", $data->profile_user->name, PHP_EOL;
echo "Usuário: ", $data->profile_user->screen_name, PHP_EOL;
echo "Foto de perfil: ", $data->profile_user->profile_image_url, PHP_EOL;
```

No meu caso, a saída foi:

```
Nome: Anderson Carlos Woss
Usuário: acwoss
Foto de perfil: http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/827606791592747008/9EdeoXRp_normal.jpg
```

---

O código inteiro seria algo como:

```php
<?php

$url = 'https://twitter.com/' . $username;

$user = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($user, [
      CURLOPT_URL             => $url,
      CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST   => 'GET',
      CURLOPT_CAINFO          => 'cacert-2017-06-07.pem',
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true,
      CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER  => false,
      CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST  => 2,
      CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER      => [
        "Content-type:text/html;charset=utf-8",
      ],
      CURLOPT_USERAGENT       => $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],
      CURLOPT_HEADER          => true,
      CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION  => true,
      CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS       => 2,
      CURLOPT_REDIR_PROTOCOLS => CURLPROTO_HTTP | CURLPROTO_HTTPS,
      CURLOPT_POSTREDIR       => 2,
      CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER     => 1,
      CURLOPT_ENCODING        => "gzip"
  ]
);

$user_info = curl_exec($user);

$header_size = curl_getinfo($user, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
$header = substr($user_info, 0, $header_size);
$body = substr($user_info, $header_size);

$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($body);

$json = $dom->getElementById("init-data")->getAttribute("value");
$data = json_decode($json);

echo "Nome: ", $data->profile_user->name, PHP_EOL;
echo "Usuário: ", $data->profile_user->screen_name, PHP_EOL;
echo "Foto de perfil: ", $data->profile_user->profile_image_url, PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: Cara, show!!! Funcionou perfeitamente, além do mais super bem explicado,  mas, `PHP_EOL` é necessário mesmo?

Comment: Não, utilizei apenas para quebrar a linha e exibir cada informação em linhas diferentes. Como serão utilizados vai depender da sua aplicação.

Comment: Entendi, cara só não entendi a parte do `input[type=hidden]` onde acho ele? Acho que vou abrir outra pergunta ja ja, bem elaborada de como obter informações do Twitter com cURL

Comment: Olhando o código fonte da página do Twitter e procurando pelo meu nome, encontrei esse elemento na linha 21801 do HTML. É um dos últimos elementos na página.

Comment: Ata vou dar uma olhada naquele `debug` obg @Anderson Carlos Woss

Comment: Como faz pra debugar os indices de `$data->user_info`?? pra ver o conteúdo?

Comment: Quem seria `$data->user_info`? Ou seria `$data->profile_user`?

Comment: Opa erro meu desculpa nem percebi...

Comment: Pode fazer `var_dump($data->profile_user)`.

Comment: Deu certinho, estou retornando com `echo json_encode($data->profile_user)` pra usar com ajax, o problema vai ser recuperar depois

Comment: Uma dúvida amigo, como estou salvando todos os dados, cookies, que vem do Twitter e salvando numa DB, e em um arquivo `.txt` nesse html debugado, é possivel encontrar algo sobre auto seguir, e receber seguidores? no caso todas as ids salvas no meu banco de dados, por exemplo loguei, e vou receber todos os seguidores com as ids salvas no banco... ali encontro algo do tipo? @Anderson