# Como decodificar este json no php?

Tags: php, json

Vi algumas perguntas parecidas aqui no satckoverflow, mas não achei resposta pra esse problema.

Tenho um Result que me traz o json a seguir:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Fri, 07 Jul 2017 19:44:04 GMT
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
callId: 12476bea-0ebc-409d-86cc-69aac003e356
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=63072000
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff

{"paginacao":{"pagina":1,"quantidadeRegistros":10,"quantidadeTotalRegistros":10}
```

Acontece que se eu usar **json_decode($resul, true)** ele não consegue separar o cabeçalho então não retorna o objeto como preciso que seria somente a partir de **{"pagina...**

Como proceder neste caso,estou usando **curl_setopt()** para consumir o json na origem

Comment: Como você está fazendo pra quê essa variável `$resul` retorne essa request com o `header`? Edite a questão e adicione o código.

Comment: Veja esta minha resposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/217424/5878

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta **remover** a opção `CURLOPT_HEADER` que retorna os headers:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
```

Ou setar `0`

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
```

E então pegue a resposta e use o `json_decode`, exemplo:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

//Define um User-agent
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);

//Retorna a resposta
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

//Resposta
$data = curl_exec($ch);

//depurando
var_dump($data);

var_dump(json_decode($data));
```

Leia mais na documentação: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.curl-setopt.php

Comment: Eu estava tendo problemas quando desativava o header, mas agora desativei conforme sua sugestão e funcionou legal.