# cURL Friendships/create, bad authentication data

Tags: php, libcurl, twitter-api

Bom com a ajuda da resposta do [Inkeliz](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/15089/inkeliz), feita [nesta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/217256/curl-retornando-offset-indefinido), eu consegui autenticação com o Twitter via formulário.

Arquivo **login.php**:

```
<?php

require_once '../modules/config.php';
require_once '../modules/class/Cookies.php';

$cookie = [];

$username = trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username'));
$password = trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'password'));

$index_url = 'https://twitter.com';

$token = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($token, [
      CURLOPT_URL             => $index_url,
      CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST   => 'GET',
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true,
      CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER  => false,
      CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST  => 2,
      CURLOPT_USERAGENT       => $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],
      //CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE      => __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'cookies' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $username . '.txt',
      CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR       => __DIR__ . SEPARATOR . 'cookies' . SEPARATOR . $username . '.txt',
      CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION   => true,
      CURLOPT_REFERER         => $index_url,
      CURLOPT_HEADER          => true,
      CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER      => ['Cookie:' . http_build_query($cookie, '', ';') . ';'],
      CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION => function ($curl, $header) use (&$cookie) {
        if (stripos($header, 'Set-Cookie:') === 0) {
          if (preg_match('/Set-Cookie:\s?(.*?)=(.*?);/i', $header, $matches)) {
            $cookie[$matches[1]] = urldecode($matches[2]);
          }
        }
        return strlen($header);
      }
    ]
);    
$access = curl_exec($token);

preg_match('/value="(.*?)" name="authenticity_token"/', $access, $matches);

$authenticity_token = $matches[1];

$session_post = "session[username_or_email]=$username&session[password]=$password&return_to_ssl=true&scribe_log=&redirect_after_login=%2F&authenticity_token=$authenticity_token";

$session_url = 'https://twitter.com/sessions';

curl_setopt_array($token, [
      CURLOPT_URL             => $session_url,
      CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST   => 'POST',
      CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS      => $session_post,
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true,
      CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER      => [
        "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        'Cookie: '. http_build_query($cookie, '', ';').';',
      ],
      CURLOPT_USERAGENT       => $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],
      CURLOPT_HEADER          => true,
      CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION  => true,
      CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS       => 2,
      CURLOPT_REDIR_PROTOCOLS => CURLPROTO_HTTP | CURLPROTO_HTTPS,
      CURLOPT_POSTREDIR       => 2,
      CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER     => 1
  ]

);
$auth = curl_exec($token);

if (isset($cookie['auth_token']))
{
  $twid = filter_var($cookie['twid'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

  Cookies::set('login_token', $cookie['ct0']);
  Cookies::set('kdt', $cookie['kdt']);
  Cookies::set('user_id', $twid);
  Cookies::set('auth_token', $cookie['auth_token']);
  Cookies::set('username', $username);

  $_SESSION[SITE_TITLE . '_session'] = $username;

  echo json_encode(array(
    "status"      => "success",
    "message"     => "Autenticação bem sucedida, estamos te redirecionando.",
  ));
}
else
{
  echo json_encode(
    array(
      "status" => "error",
      'message'=> "Não foi possível autenticar com o Twitter.",
    ));
}
```

Repare que salvo dois tokens em *cookies*: `auth_token` e `login_token`, sendo `auth_token = $authenticity_token;` e `login_token = cookie[ct0]`, **ct0** vem do Twitter.

O login está ok, depois tenho o `cURL` de obter informações do usuário logado, que também consegui faze-lo com a ajuda [desta minha pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/217415/obter-informa%C3%A7%C3%B5es-do-twitter-sem-o-uso-da-api-com-curl) e respondida pelo [Anderson Carlos Woss](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/5878/anderson-carlos-woss), também está ok, recupero, `screen_name`, `name`, `foto`, *entre outros*...

Agora vem a minha dúvida, eu sei que pra utilizar a API precisa de um token, e também sei que esse token é o `cookie` **ct0**, mas não sei como utilizar, veja me código.

Arquivo, **friend.php**

```
<?php

require_once '../modules/config.php';
require_once '../modules/class/Cookies.php';


$username = Cookies::get('username');

$friend_url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friendships/create.json';

$friend = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($friend, [
        CURLOPT_URL             => $friend_url,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER  => 1,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST  => 2,
        CURLOPT_CAINFO          => ROOT . 'modules' . SEPARATOR . 'cacert' . SEPARATOR . 'cacert-2017-06-07.pem',
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST   => 'POST',
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS      => 'screen_name=' . $username,
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT       => $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],
        CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR       => __DIR__ . SEPARATOR . 'cookies' . SEPARATOR . $username . '.txt',
        CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION   => true,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER      => [
            "Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8",
      ],
        CURLOPT_HEADER          => 0,
    ]

);

$response  = curl_exec($friend);

var_dump($response);
```

Ao rodar o código no navegador me retorna o `error 215 Bad Authentication data`.

Bom como eu sei que é o **cookie[ct0]** que devo usar?, De uma olhada nesta pergunta no [SO inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44894394/logic-using-curl-php-and-twitter-without-using-api?answertab=votes#tab-top), muita (gambiarra) que tenho certeza que só com `cURL`, resolve.

**EDIT 1**

Class **Cookie.php**

```
<?php

class Cookies {
    private static $storage = array();

    public static function get($key) {

        if( isset($_COOKIE[$key])) {
            return $_COOKIE[$key];
        } else {
            if(isset(static::$storage[$key])) {
                return static::$storage[$key];
            }

        }
    }

    public static function set($key, $value) {
        static::$storage[$key] = $value;
        setcookie($key, $value, time() + (2 * 3600), '/');
    }

    public static function remove($key, $value) {
        setcookie($key, $value, time()-3600, '/');
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2**

Conforme *Inkeliz* mencionou nos comentários o **token** está num arquivo JS, e consegui extrair este **token**, porém como devo utiliza-lo agora? alguém tem ideia? Veja meu código:

```
require_once './system/config.php';

$TwitterUser = null;

if (isset($_SESSION[SITE_TITLE . '_SESSION'])) {
    $TwitterUser = $_SESSION[SITE_TITLE . '_SESSION'];
}

$twitter_url_js = 'https://abs.twimg.com/k/pt/init.pt.8a8c7bc568e38012a94b.js';

$getToken = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($getToken, [
        CURLOPT_URL                         => $twitter_url_js,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST   => 'GET',
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER  => false,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST  => 2,
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT               => $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],
        CURLOPT_HEADER                  => true,
    ]
);

$token = curl_exec($getToken);

preg_match('/\"([A-z0-9%]{114})\";/', $token, $matches);

$auth_token = $matches[1];

$friend_post = http_build_query([
        'screen_name' => $TwitterUser
    ]
);

$twitter_friend_url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friendships/create.json';

curl_setopt_array($getToken, [
        CURLOPT_URL                         => $twitter_friend_url,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST       => 'POST',
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS          => $friend_post,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER  => false,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST  => 2,
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT               => $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],
        CURLOPT_HEADER                  => true,
    ]
);

$friend = curl_exec($getToken);

var_dump($friend);
```

Bom com o `var_dump($friend);` recebo como resposta isto:

```
'HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
content-length: 62
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
date: Sun, 16 Jul 2017 23:41:51 GMT
server: tsa_d
set-cookie: guest_id=v1%3A150024851187284588; Domain=.twitter.com; Path=/; Expires=Tue, 16-Jul-2019 23:41:51 UTC
strict-transport-security: max-age=631138519
x-connection-hash: 8c0410547b9456c4ac13f360b8c8dbc3
x-response-time: 132
x-tsa-request-body-time: 0

{"errors":[{"code":215,"message":"Bad Authentication data."}]}' (length=472)
```

**EDIT 3**

Troquei algumas informações no *HTTP* agora me retorna `200 OK`:

```
$twitter_friend_url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friendships/create.json';

curl_setopt_array($getToken, [
        CURLOPT_URL                         => $twitter_friend_url,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST       => 'OPTIONS',
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER          => [
      'Access-Control-Request-Method: POST',
      'Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization,x-csrf-token,x-twitter-active-user,x-twitter-auth-type',
      'DNT: 1',
      'Origin: https://twitter.com' 
        ], 
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER  => false,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST  => 2,
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT               => $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],
        CURLOPT_HEADER                  => true,
    ]
);

$friend = curl_exec($getToken);

var_dump($friend);
```

Comment: Esse token não é cookie, esse token está no JS do Twitter e esse javascript precisa do cookie. :)

Comment: Tem ideia de como fazer? @Inkeliz

Comment: Qual seria a dificuldade? O token está aqui (https://abs.twimg.com/k/pt/init.pt.8a8c7bc568e38012a94b.js), basta pesquisar por "AAAAAAAAAAAA", acredito que um `/\"([A-z0-9%]{114})\";/` resolva o caso. Já o CT0 é usado para o CSRF-Token, creio eu. Não sei se o nome desse JS muda, então se não conseguir acessar veja o tráfego (F12 > Network) e veja o primeiro JS que geralmente é obtido, com o prefixo de `init.`.

Comment: @Inkeliz, sim eu tentei, a dificuldade é que não consigo usar o token com curl, se você tiver uma resposta base para minha pergunta, posso colocar meu codigo no mediafire amanhã pra vc dar uma olhada mais detalhada.

Comment: @Inkeliz editei minha pergunta, veja que extraí o token como você citou nos comentários, porém, como usar o cURL para fazer o que preciso? sem aquelas gambiarras usadas na pergunta no SoUS, bom, para mais detalhes preciso de uma resposta, creio que você tem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você monitorou as informações enviadas para o Twitter então deveria de ter observado a presença dos cabeçalhos de `authorization`, `x-csrf-token`, `x-twitter-active-user` e `x-twitter-auth-type`.

Todos eles não estão presentes no seu código.

---

É necessário que utilize algo como:

```
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
  'origin: https://twitter.com',
  'cookie: ' . $todos_os_cookies_do_twitter,

  'authorization: Bearer ' . $auth_token,
  'x-csrf-token: ' . $ct0,

  'x-twitter-auth-type: OAuth2Session',
  'x-twitter-active-user: yes',

  'referer: https://twitter.com',
]
```

Considerando que o `$ct0` é o valor do cookie com o nome de `ct0`.

Já o `$auth_token` é o token que está "embutido" dentro do JS (poderia usar o `preg_match('/\"([A-Z0-9%]{114})\";/i', $token, $matches);`, que o que está usando no código).

O `$todos_os_cookies_do_twitter` é todos os cookies que tem do Twitter.

Este `authorization` aparentemente sempre inicia por `AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA`, o que [torna fácil encontra-lo no JS](https://abs.twimg.com/k/pt/init.pt.8a8c7bc568e38012a94b.js).

Além de claro deve fazer a requisição como `POST` e não `OPTIONS`. O `OPTIONS` é usado como [*prefight*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685678/cors-how-do-preflight-an-httprequest). Então você deve usar `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST'` ou `CURLOPT_POST => 1`.

Depois é preciso que defina o `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` com os dados, coisa que testá diferente no seu código. No caso utilize exatamente como o Twitter utiliza, que é:

```
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query(
        ['challenges_passed' => false,
        'handles_challenges' => 1,
        'include_blocked_by' => true,
        'include_blocking' => true,
        'include_can_dm' => true,
        'include_followed_by' => true,
        'include_mute_edge' => true,
        'skip_status' => true,
        'user_id' => $id_twitter_quem_quer_seguir
    ], '', '&', PHP_QUERY_RFC3986),
```

Não sei o que indica as variáveis, exceto a última `user_id` que é quem você quer seguir, para exemplo usei [`83430421`](https://twitter.com/DaTweekaz), enfim o `$id_twitter_quem_quer_seguir` deve ser o ID do usuário que irá receber o seguidor.

---

Além disso certifique que o `$auth_token` está correto.

Comment: Tudo certo, porem ainda recebo `{"errors":[{"code":32,"message":"Could not authenticate you."}]}' (length=485)`, mas 200 ok em `friendships/create` e no token do `JS`, sabe a solução para isto?

Comment: Testei aqui, não tem nenhum erro. Vou editar para incluir todos os headers ao invés do `//...`.

Comment: não está indo está retornando `HTTP/1.1 401 Authorization Required
`

Comment: Este ocorre porque o access token está incorreto. O outro ("could not authenticate you") é quando os cookies não são enviados. Aparentemente.

Comment: Vixe, eu tenho tudo, vou por meu código do pastebin. Era pra funcionar.

Comment: veja : https://pastebin.com/s82ndBKa

Comment: Os cookies estão claramente errados. Os cookies devem ser no formato `nome=valor; outro_nome=outro_valor;`, por isso é usado `['Cookie:' . http_build_query($cookie, '', ';') . ';']`  no seu proprio código, que foi uma resposta que dei a algum tempo atrás. Isso é feito justamente para fazer `nome_do_cookie=valor;`. O separador é `;` ao invés de `&`.

Comment: veja: print1: http://prntscr.com/fy7u59, print2: http://prntscr.com/fy7ufa estou quase certo né?

Comment: Leia a documentação já evitaria a maior parte dos erros, sério, desde o cURL que já diz como espera os cookies. O `http_build_query` espera um array, ou seja `http_build_query($_COOKIE, '', ';') . ';' ;` já faz tudo, *tirando os problemas de seguranças aplicáveis*.

Comment: perdoa-me, eu li a documentação e concertei e não lhe avisei, fiz da forma que você colocou aí resolveu, porém `HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
`; é retornado agora. MDS um problema atrás do outro.

Comment: Qual o texto? Se for `You can't follow yourself.` é porque você está tentando seguir a se próprio, devido ao que definiu em `$user_id    = Cookies::get('twid');`. O `$id_twitter_quem_quer_seguir` é o ID de querm você quer seguir e não o ID de quem está conectado.

Comment: Arrumei, grato @Inkeliz, agora vou partir para lógica de tokens salvo na DB seguirem usuários conectados.