# Como entender as requisições requeridas no cURL?

Tags: php, libcurl, http-headers

Ontem abri uma pergunta fui obrigado apaga-la, pois eu não consegui perguntar corretamente.
Esta pergunta vou tenta-la explica-la por partes, vamos lá.

1 - Monitorei o Twitter, seguindo uma pessoa, obtive estes protocolos:

```
curl "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friendships/create.json"
-H "Origin: https://twitter.com"
-H "x-csrf-token: ab9d9188841188d57c1e3e2ed1b90325"
-H "authorization: Bearer AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAPYXBAAAAAAACLXUNDekMxqa8h^%^2F40K4moUkGsoc^%^3DTYfbDKbT3jJPCEVnMYqilB28NHfOPqkca3qaAxGfsyKCs0wRbw"
-H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
-H "Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01"
-H "Referer: https://twitter.com/pdosilva1020"
-H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36"
-H "x-twitter-auth-type: OAuth2Session"
-H "X-Twitter-Active-User: yes"
--data "challenges_passed=false^&handles_challenges=1^&include_blocked_by=true^&include_blocking=true^&include_can_dm=true^&include_followed_by=true^&include_mute_edge=true^&skip_status=true^&user_id=876965710978830337" --compressed &

curl "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friendships/create.json"
-X OPTIONS -H "access-control-request-method: POST"
-H "origin: https://twitter.com"
-H "accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br"
-H "accept-language: pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4"
-H "user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36"
-H "accept: */*"
-H "referer: https://twitter.com/pdosilva1020"
-H "authority: api.twitter.com"
-H "access-control-request-headers: authorization,x-csrf-token,x-twitter-active-user,x-twitter-auth-type" --compressed &

curl "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friendships/create.json"
-H "origin: https://twitter.com"
-H "accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br"
-H "x-csrf-token: ab9d9188841188d57c1e3e2ed1b90325"
-H "accept-language: pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4"
-H "authorization: Bearer AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAPYXBAAAAAAACLXUNDekMxqa8h^%^2F40K4moUkGsoc^%^3DTYfbDKbT3jJPCEVnMYqilB28NHfOPqkca3qaAxGfsyKCs0wRbw"
-H "cookie: personalization_id=^\^"v1_AEx3/TzL4vC/TVoRp7A9GQ==^\^"; guest_id=v1^%^3A150404403827902852; ads_prefs=^\^"HBESAAA=^\^"; kdt=qxgHjAztSnnZFJwieBRWJxoVGMibzs2KWwO1pLDF; remember_checked_on=1; twid=^\^"u=876929501132992512^\^"; auth_token=1f334266ebf70a5fe9ec0d01fe33d4192253ec9d; external_referer=OTZIBTkFw3vkkAaSWI6wkvUDrlzaIZB6BnbGZOK1XnQ^%^3D^|0^|8e8t2xd8A2w^%^3D; lang=pt; ct0=ab9d9188841188d57c1e3e2ed1b90325; _ga=GA1.2.1021364707.1504044044; _gid=GA1.2.2049121336.1504044044; _gat=1; dnt=1; _twitter_sess=BAh7CSIKZmxhc2hJQzonQWN0aW9uQ29udHJvbGxlcjo6Rmxhc2g6OkZsYXNo^%^250ASGFzaHsABjoKQHVzZWR7ADoPY3JlYXRlZF9hdGwrCJlMfDJeAToMY3NyZl9p^%^250AZCIlODcyNzQyMDU1OGZlOTdhZWZkMmE2MTM4YTNkNzhlNzE6B2lkIiViZjNl^%^250AN2Y3Y2NjNDM3YWFhNjRjMjdjNzNhMTExMmE5Yw^%^253D^%^253D--a8f7846f97c012459cf7393fdc6a954aac5ee7c3"
-H "x-twitter-auth-type: OAuth2Session"
-H "user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36"
-H "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
-H "accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01"
-H "referer: https://twitter.com/pdosilva1020"
-H "authority: api.twitter.com"
-H "x-twitter-active-user: yes"
--data "challenges_passed=false^&handles_challenges=1^&include_blocked_by=true^&include_blocking=true^&include_can_dm=true^&include_followed_by=true^&include_mute_edge=true^&skip_status=true^&user_id=876965710978830337" --compressed &
```

Onde **referer: https://twitter.com/pdosilva1020** foi a conta que foi seguida pela minha.

Consegui com este código seguir a pessoa:

```
$bearer = 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAPYXBAAAAAAACLXUNDekMxqa8h%2F40K4moUkGsoc%3DTYfbDKbT3jJPCEVnMYqilB28NHfOPqkca3qaAxGfsyKCs0wRbw';

$followCurlInit = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($followCurlInit, [
        CURLOPT_URL                         => $this->_url,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST       => 'POST',
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER  => false,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST  => 2,
        CURLOPT_HEADER                  => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER          => [
            'origin: https://twitter.com',
            'cookie:' . http_build_query($_COOKIE, '', ';') . ';',
          'authorization: Bearer ' . $bearer,
          'x-csrf-token: ' . Cookies::get('ct0'),
          'Referer: https://twitter.com/pdosilva1020',
          'x-twitter-auth-type: OAuth2Session',
          'x-twitter-active-user: yes',
        ],
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query([
      'challenges_passed'   => false,
      'handles_challenges'  => 1,
      'include_blocked_by'  => true,
      'include_blocking'        => true,
      'include_can_dm'          => true,
      'include_followed_by' => true,
      'include_mute_edge'   => true,
      'skip_status'                 => true,
      'user_id'                         => '876965710978830337',
    ], '', '&', PHP_QUERY_RFC3986),
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT               => $this->_userAgent,
        CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE          => $this->_cookieFileLocation,
    ]
);

$this->_webPage = curl_exec($followCurlInit);
var_dump($this->_webPage);
$this->_status = curl_getinfo($followCurlInit, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

curl_setopt_array($followCurlInit, [
        CURLOPT_URL                         => $this->_url,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST       => 'OPTIONS',
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER  => false,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST  => 2,
        CURLOPT_HEADER                  => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER          => [
            'origin: https://twitter.com',
            'access-control-request-method: POST',
            'accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br',
            'accept-language: pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4',
            'accept: */*',
            'referer: https://twitter.com/pdosilva1020',
            'authority: api.twitter.com',
            'access-control-request-headers: authorization,x-csrf-token,x-twitter-active-user,x-twitter-auth-type',
        ],
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT               => $this->_userAgent,
    ]
);

$this->_webPage = curl_exec($followCurlInit);
$this->_status = curl_getinfo($followCurlInit, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
```

O objetivo é ser seguido, tenho todos os `cookies ct0` salvos em minha `database`, (contas fakes), onde recupero os `ct0`, mas tem um porém,

recebo false neste código abaixo, ele não me retorna nada:

```
curl_setopt_array($followCurlInit, [
        CURLOPT_URL                         => $this->_url,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST       => 'OPTIONS',
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER  => false,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST  => 2,
        CURLOPT_HEADER                  => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER          => [
            'origin: https://twitter.com',
            'access-control-request-method: POST',
            'accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br',
            'accept-language: pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4',
            'accept: */*',
            'referer: https://twitter.com/pdosilva1020',
            'authority: api.twitter.com',
            'access-control-request-headers: authorization,x-csrf-token,x-twitter-active-user,x-twitter-auth-type',
        ],
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT               => $this->_userAgent,
    ]
);

$this->_webPage = curl_exec($followCurlInit);
var_dump($this->_webPage);
$this->_status = curl_getinfo($followCurlInit, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
```

Quero entender como funciona essas requisições monitoradas, sei que o `cookie ct0` e o `user_id` vai ser utilizado para fazer me seguir. Alguém pode me ajudar pelo menos com a dúvida do `CURL`?

Comment: Método `OPTIONS` é de se esperar que vá retornar nada mesmo, só cabeçalho. Depois, não é apenas o ` ct0` que precisa, mas também o `access_token`, definido no `authorization`. Se estiver tentado "seguir a si próprio" dará erro também.

Comment: @Inkeliz, editei a pergunta.

Comment: Não está claro qual o problema. Você mesmo diz "Consegui com este código seguir a pessoa", então este código funciona e não há problema algum. O último código não faz o menor sentido o `OPTIONS` é um [pre-fight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request), que não tem nada haver aqui. "Alguém pode me ajudar pelo menos com a dúvida do CURL?", qual á duvida? Se você quer entender o motivo de cada requisição? O código que diz funcionar é esperado que funcione, inclusive [é o mesmo daqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/221606/15089), inclusive o OP cometeu o mesmo erro.

Comment: Funciona, porém quero ser seguido e não seguir. Entendes-te?

Comment: Então, basta inverter a ordem. Isso não tem nada haver com o cURL. Se você é o ID `1234`, então basta definir ele em `user_id` e usar as outras contas (usando o `auth_token`, o `ct0` e o `_twitter_sess`) e pronto.

Comment: Teria um exemplo? pois tentei e não consegui.

Comment: Está tentando criar um robô de follow? 
Esses cookies tem expiração, não acredito que vá conseguir reutilizá-lo.

Comment: Expira não. Tanto é que se eu mandar pra vc uns cookies que foi criado a uns dois meses atras tu consegue entrar na minha conta.

Comment: [Aqui tem mais](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/follow-search-get-users/api-reference/get-friends-ids.html) sobre a API. Não precisa ser cURL, vc pode usar javascript com ajax, é só entender quais são os parâmetros necessários para obter uma resposta.

Comment: A requisição retornará em um formato JSON para vc consumir, no php, pode ser convertido com: `$dados_em_array = json_decode($_POST);` a documentação fala quais são os parâmetros que vc precisa enviar, para obter a saída que pretende.

Answer (score 1):

[cURL](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.curl.php) é uma forma de consumir uma API ou página html, seu retorno é renderizado pelo browser.

A [documentação](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/follow-search-get-users/api-reference/get-friends-ids.html) está descrevendo os itens que podem ser fornecidos e acessados:

> **curl**: é a URL chamada
>   **-H**: são os headers
>   **--data**: são os parâmetros

Para acessar via cURL, você pode utilizar um método como esse por exemplo:

```
function simple_cUrl($url, $post = array(), $get = array())
{
  $url = explode('?', $url, 2);
  if (count($url) === 2) {
      $temp_get = array();
      parse_str($url[1], $temp_get);
      $get = array_merge($get, $temp_get);
  }

  $ch = curl_init($url[0] . "?" . http_build_query($get));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
        /* AQUI VOCÊ COLOCA OS HEADERS QUE ELE PEDE:
        -H "Origin: https://twitter.com"
        -H "x-csrf-token: ab9d9188841188d57c1e3e2ed1b90325"
        -H "authorization: Bearer AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAPYXBAAAAAAACLXUNDekMxqa8h^%^2F40K4moUkGsoc^%^3DTYfbDKbT3jJPCEVnMYqilB28NHfOPqkca3qaAxGfsyKCs0wRbw"
        -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
        -H "Accept: application/json, text/javascript, *\/*; q=0.01"
        -H "Referer: https://twitter.com/pdosilva1020"
        -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36"
        -H "x-twitter-auth-type: OAuth2Session"
        -H "X-Twitter-Active-User: yes"
        */
         //igual o exemplo abaixo do primeiro -H:
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, "Origin: https://twitter.com");
        return curl_exec($ch);
}
```

E consumi-lo passando os parâmetros, conforme o primeiro exemplo:

```
 $resultado = simple_cUrl('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friendships/create.json', 
      array(
        'challenges_passed' => false,
        'handles_challenges' => 1,
        'include_blocked_by' => true,
        'include_blocking' => true,
        'include_can_dm' => true,
        'include_mute_edge' => true
      ...etc
     ));
```

Depois, basta coletar o dados do que foi consumido em um array:

`$saida_final = json_decode($resultado, true);`

Comment: Ivan, tem certeza que cURL tem alguma coisa a ver com renderização? Pergunto pois o programa serve única e exclusivamente para fazer transferência de dados usando URLs ([fonte](https://ec.haxx.se/curl-does.html)). Salvo engano, a parte onde você afirma que cURL "renderiza" algo não está correta.

Comment: Verdade, quem renderiza é o browser,  eu tentei deixar de uma forma mais simplificada o entendimento, vcs não deixam escapar nada  mesmo kkkk...

Comment: Muita coisa aqui vai servir de fonte de conhecimento pra alguém no futuro... acho que é por isso que a gente aprende a ser chato aqui. hahahha