# Twitter API com CURL

Tags: php, libcurl, twitter-api

**OBS: [O CÓDIGO COMPLETO ESTÁ AQUI](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/233554/como-entender-as-requisi%C3%A7%C3%B5es-requeridas-no-curl), porém fiz este ajuste para receber os `cookies`**

Estou tentando ler os arquivos de cookies para fazer as requisições necessárias parar obter o resultado que eu espero, veja meu código:

```
$tokens = ['_twitter_sess', 'ct0', 'auth_token'];

        foreach (glob($this->_cookieFile) as $file) {
            $pointer = fopen($file, 'r');
        while (!feof($pointer)) {
        $line = fgets($pointer);

        foreach ($tokens as $token) {
          if (stripos($line, $token) !== false) {
            var_dump($line);
            curl_setopt_array($request, [
                                CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE  => $line,
                                CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER          => [
                          'origin: https://twitter.com',
                          'authorization: Bearer ' . $bearer,
                          'x-csrf-token: ' . $line,
                          'referer: https://twitter.com/',
                          'x-twitter-auth-type: OAuth2Session',
                          'x-twitter-active-user: yes',
                        ],
                         CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query([
                              'challenges_passed'   => false,
                              'handles_challenges'  => 1,
                              'include_blocked_by'  => true,
                              'include_blocking'    => true,
                              'include_can_dm'      => true,
                              'include_followed_by' => true,
                              'include_mute_edge'   => true,
                              'skip_status'         => true,
                              'user_id'             => Session::get('username'),
                                ], '', '&', PHP_QUERY_RFC3986),
                            ]
                        );
            break;
          }
        }
        }
        }
```

Porém ao dar um `var_dump` em `$line`, recebo como retorno:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso ler cada linha em um `array associativo` ou ler todos os cookies de uma vez.

Então como retorno do meu `cURL` me retorna:

```
'{"errors":[{"code":220,"message":"Your credentials do not allow access to this resource."}]}' (length=92)
```

Comment: Que array associativo seria esse?

Comment: Exemplo: `$line['ct0'`], `$line['_twitter_sess']` ... entende?

Comment: Isso é um formato [Netscape](https://curl.haxx.se/rfc/cookie_spec.html), neste link tem toda a documentação. Além disso se você estiver pegando o cookie você não precisa usar esse formato, você tem o `CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION` que permite extrair isso direto do cabeçalho. Além disso você não precisa de qualquer array associativo, ao menos o cURL já suporta o formato Netscape se você usar o "cookie engine" (i.e `COOKIEFILE` ou `COOKIELIST`), eu [disse isso aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/234444/netscape-http-cookie-file-usar-arquivo-salvo/234881#234881).

Comment: @Inkeliz, mas se estou salvado o arquivo, qual a lógica em não usa-lo? O.o sim eu vi esta resposta. Quero usar o arquivo, como tu disse na resposta, `CUROPT_COOKIE` resolveria certo ? porém tenho uns 7 cookies salvos no formato **Netscape**. Preciso de todos.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Transformar conteúdo de arquivo em cookies](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/234756/transformar-conte%c3%bado-de-arquivo-em-cookies)

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Duplicata, mas cade a resposta?... Vou apagar aquela e deixar esta.

Comment: Duplicata no sentido de você estar poluindo a comunidade com perguntas repetidas porque não obteve a resposta. Isso não é uma boa prática e não deve ser incentivada. Se já fez a pergunta antes e ninguém respondeu, talvez seja interessante rever a pergunta observando o que pode melhorar ou oferecer uma recompensa.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, você está certo, perdoa-me, porém minha pergunta está completamente diferente agora. Ta tenso resolver este problema.

Comment: Se já está em arquivo, usa o `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` ele aceita este formato, normalmente. Veja a documentação, ele aceita tanto no formato Netscape quanto no formato do "Set-Cookie".

Comment: @Inkeliz, mas ele lê todos os arquivos da pasta? eu preciso colocar no caso preciso apenas do `twitter_sess` e `auth_token`, já que ct0 salvo em um banco.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se realmente quiser um array, o que por mim não faz o menor sentido e me parece ser um que essa questão é um "Problema XY". Mas enfim, basta "explodir" por cada `\t`.

Logo, supondo que esteja em string:

```
$cookie = '# Netscape HTTP Cookie File

.example.org    TRUE    /   FALSE   1507286655  remember_me true
.example.org    TRUE    /   FALSE   1507286655  APISID  DijdSAOAjgwijnhFMndsjiejfdSDNSgfsikasASIfgijsowITITeoknsd
.example.org    TRUE    /   FALSE   1507286655  static_files    iy1aBf1JhQR';


$array = [];

foreach(array_slice(explode("\n", $cookie), 2) as $linha){

    $colunas = explode("\t", $linha);
    $array[$colunas[5]] = $colunas[6];

}
```

Resultado (`var_dump($array)`):

```
array(3) { ["remember_me"]=> string(5) "true " ["APISID"]=> string(58) "DijdSAOAjgwijnhFMndsjiejfdSDNSgfsikasASIfgijsowITITeoknsd " ["static_files"]=> string(11) "iy1aBf1JhQR" }
```

---

A ideia é simples, ignora as duas primeiras linhas (`array_slice(..., 2)`)  depois por cada linha quebra por tab (`\n`) e então obtem as informações de nome e valor.

---

Porque acho isso totalmente equivocado:

1. Você tem recursos nativos para isso no cURL, todos os recursos que usam o mecanismo de gerenciamento de cookie do cURL lidam bem com este formato Netscape.
2. Você tem como usar o `CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION` para filtrar os cookies, caso esteja fazendo uma requisição para salvar tais cookies.
3. Você pode ainda também usar o `CURLINFO_COOKIELIST` para obter a mesma informação, filtra-lo e salva-lo, restando apenas os dados que interessa.
4. Você está armazenando dados desnecessários, piorando a performance tendo que filtrar isso a toda execução, sem nenhum beneficio.

Comment: Bom eu ví a sua resposta [AQUI](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/234444/netscape-http-cookie-file-usar-arquivo-salvo/234881#234881), Entendi o conceito, vou rever meus casos, porém eu tenho vários arquivos no formato Netscape @Inkeliz, preciso usar todos. Acho que vc já sacou o que quero fazer. Vou marcar como resolvido já que a sua resposta responde a minha pergunta.

Comment: @Inkeliz, a dúvida dele era a mesma que a minha OAKSOKOAKS eu tbm estou salvando todos os cookies em arquivos separados como pode ver [aqui] (http://prntscr.com/ghrc8u) mas tem um porém, tanto o `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` quanto o `COOKIELIST` não vai listar todos corretos?, vc disse que tem o `HEADERFUNCTION` porém eu pego esses cookies no login, salvo no TXT pra depois fazer a requisição na API, Creio eu que ele não precisa disso tudo, Agora somos dois em dúvida, como ler todos esses COOKIES sem essa gambiarra aí ? O.o

Comment: O `HEADERFUNCTION` permite criar uma função de leitura do cabeçalho, você é livre para criar como quiser o filtro que quiser e armazenar como quiser. No caso, você pode pegar apenas os cookies que quer (exemplo, `a`, `b`, `c` e ignorar os `z`, `y`). Com um pouco de performance em mente você iria armazenar apenas como `a=valor;b=valor2;c=valor3;`, poderia armazenar no banco de dados numa tabela e então depois só usar `CURLOPT_COOKIE` ele já estará formatado corretamente. O COOKIELIST lista todos no formato Netscape (o mesmo do OP), dai filtraria e salva (ou invés de salvar e filtrar sempre).

Comment: Show, no caso ao invés de salvar no arquivo salvo direto no banco? e depois uso `CURLOPT_COOKIE` pra recuperar estes cookies? Bom irei salvar em arquivos e no banco pra ver o que acontece, gostei da resposta.

Comment: `COOKIE_FILE` O nome do arquivo que contém os dados do cookie. O arquivo de cookie pode estar no formato Netscape, ou simplesmente cabeçalhos de estilo HTTP descartados em um arquivo. Se o nome for uma string vazia, nenhum cookie será carregado, mas o gerenciamento de cookies ainda está ativado. Então minha lógica ta certa, se está em arquivos com nomes diferentes eu preciso desse array com um loop.

Comment: O que não faz sentido é você ter lixo dentro do arquivo. Se você quiser também pode apagar as linhas desnecessárias do arquivo apenas uma única vez, o correto seria nem sequer armazenar as informações desnecessárias. Poderá até criar uma flag `# X` ou uma coluna no banco de dados, se houver tal informação indica que os dados estão limpos e passar direto para o `COOKIEFILE`. Essa é a questão, você fez uma pergunta achando que essa era a única solução, mas não explica a necessidade disto, [o problema de fato](https://goo.gl/j1Lu8b), executar esse "filtro" toda hora é um gasto desnecessário